# "This statement holds" vs "This statement holds true"

Tags: differences

Is there any difference in usage or connotation between the statements

> This equation holds.

and

> This equation holds true.

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To hold* and *to hold true* are essentially the same thing.

Indeed, the *Oxford English Dictionary* lists them under the same sense, with another:

> **hold, *v.***
>
> 23.c. To be or remain valid; to subsist; to be in force; to apply. Also ***to hold good***, ***to hold true***.

I think both are fine when talking about an equation, although if the equation somehow deals with [logical truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_truth), you may want to be careful saying it *holds true*.